# Old MAC Address on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, networking, mac, osx-yosemite, mac-address

My computer MAC Address has been registered in a specific wired LAN network. But yesterday, I had my laptop repaired and the motherboard was replaced. Therefore, it has a new MAC Address and it cannot connect to the network anymore.

How can I find the old MAC Address, so that I can possibly spoof it to get back on the network?
Unfortunately for various reasons it is not possible to add the new MAC to the registry.

I am using Yosemite version 10.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, the operating system keeps a record of almost everything, including the connections made. After playing around a bit (and help of some others), I could find the old MAC address in the following file:

```
/private/var/log/daily.out
```

Since I am looking for the wired network, I need to search for en0 and it gives me something like this:

```
en0   1500  <Link#4>    01:02:03:04:05:06        0     0        2     0     0
```

which contains my MAC address.

Comment: What is the point of answering your own question, 4 minutes after having asked it?

Comment: So that someone with the same problem in the future can benefit from the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. For difficult questions, though.